# convert ASCII value to a character based on specific char in php

Tags: php

I'd like to ask dumb question.
How could I convert @48@49@50 based on @ char ?
In PHP, understand that chr() function is used to convert a ASCII value to a character.
48 is 0.
49 is 1.
And 50 is 2.
May I know how to convert @48@49@50 as 012 and how to store 012 in one variable ?
Eg- $num = 012

Comment: Please share what you **have** attempted. (show your codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `preg_replace_callback()` here with the regex pattern `@\d+`.  As we capture each `@\d+` match, use `chr()` on that match to generate the ASCII character replacement.

```php
$input = "@48@49@50";
$out = preg_replace_callback(
    "/@(\d+)/",
    function($m) { return chr($m[1]); },
    $input
);

echo $out;  // 012
```